# Python + Selenium find_element_by_xpath returns dict

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, findelement

-Version-
Python : 3.6.8
Selenium : 3.141.0

I try this.

```
total_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('Valid X Path').text
print(total_page)
```

but,

> AttributeError : "dict' object has no attribute 'text'

I Knew....
The find_element~ function returns Dict type, not WebElement.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing the same issue when I am using Chromedriver. The workaround I am currently using is to use another driver (in this case Firefox works for me).

[image: Chrome vs Firefox driver]

EDIT: I tried to uninstall and reinstall the latest chromedriver and that seems to fix the problem for me as well.
[image: Latest Chromedriver]

Comment: this is the answer. using the latest chromedriver fixed this issue. @bk-lim

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using

```
total_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('Valid X Path').text
```

and change on new way, coz that one will be deprecated in the future:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "valid_xpath")
print(el.text)
```

anyway, I see the problem, but is not reproduced for me...

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
AttributeError : "dict' object has no attribute 'text'
```

...implies that *`find_element_by_xpath()`* is returning a *`dict`* type of object which is a bit unexpected and something is wrong somewhere within your code.

---

### Deep Dive

This error started showing up recently in some of the usecases:

[image: dict_object]

where as [`@titusfortner` mentions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10171#issuecomment-1003050785) `find_element()` was returning *JSON Wire Protocol signature for elements* instead of *a w3c response from the driver*.

This issue can be reproduced with `w3c` set as *`False`* as follows:

```
options.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
```

---

### Recomendations

In such cases, it is recommended:

- Not to set *`w3c`* at all and go as per the default configurations.
- Do not use the *`desired_capabilities`* key
- Avoid bypassing the [sandbox security](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md) unless you got a specific usecase to do so.

However, it is also important to ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current release of [***Version 4.1.3***](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/CHANGES).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v99.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.51/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome= 99.0* (as per [chromedriver=99.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt)).